# Parse yaml file to predefined struct in go

Tags: go, struct, yaml

I’ve multiple yaml files which need to be parsed and have exactly the same structure

```
schema: "1.0.0"
id: test
version: "1.2.3"


dependency :
  - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api
         group: test
         properties:
             name: app
             url: appUrl

  - name: backend
    type: mongoDb
    path: be
    install:
       - name: db
         type: mongo
    provides:
       - name: api
         properties:
            url: url
```

> The schema section is mandatory for all the yaml which the app should
>   get always
>
> The dependency tag can contain 1..n entries with mandatory fields
>   ,name, type, cwd
>
> The dependency tag can (or not) contain `install` section with `name`
>   and `properties` which is mandatory
>
> The dependency tag can (or not) contain `provides` section with `name`
>   and which is mandatory
>
> The install can have properties and the provides also can have
>   properties

I am using a [yaml parser](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) to parse the files but my question is how in Golang I can build struct that when I parse the doc it will automatically fill the main struct and will include the sub structs (such as dependency/ install sections )

I have tried something like

```
type main struct {
    schema struct {
        schema  string
        id int
        version string
    }

    dependency struct {
        name  string
        type string
        cwd string

    install struct {
        name  string
    }


}
```

In the install section, it can be group or type or both and it can have also properties section, so I'm not sure how to build
some generic /extendable struct which I use to parse the document (the document have close list of properties, what I put in the example describe the most options)

I use this lib to parse the doc

[yaml parser](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your struct definition should be something like this

```
type Yaml struct {
    Schema     string
    ID         string
    Version    string
    Dependency []Dependency
}

type Dependency struct {
    Name     string
    Type     string
    CWD      string
    Install  []Install
    Provides []Provide
}

type Install struct {
    Name       string
    Group      string
    Type       string
    Properties Properties
}

type Properties struct {
    Name string
    URL  string
}

type Provide struct {
    Name       string
    Properties Properties
}
```

Here is full sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

var data = `
schema: "1.0.0"
id: test
version: "1.2.3"


dependency :
  - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api
         group: test
         properties:
             name: app
             url: appUrl

  - name: backend
    type: mongoDb
    path: be
    install:
       - name: db
         type: mongo
    provides:
       - name: api
         properties:
             url: url
`

type Yaml struct {
    Schema     string
    ID         string
    Version    string
    Dependency []Dependency
}

type Dependency struct {
    Name     string
    Type     string
    CWD      string
    Install  []Install
    Provides []Provide
}

type Install struct {
    Name       string
    Group      string
    Type       string
    Properties Properties
}

type Properties struct {
    Name string
    URL  string
}

type Provide struct {
    Name       string
    Properties Properties
}

func main() {
    y := Yaml{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &y)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", y)

}
```

Output

```
{Schema:1.0.0 ID:test Version:1.2.3 Dependency:[{Name:ui Type:runner CWD:/ui Install:[{Name:api Group:test Type: Properties:{Name:appURL:appUrl}}] Provides:[]} {Name:backend Type:mongoDb CWD: Install:[{Name:db Group: Type:mongo Properties:{Name: URL:}}] Provides:[{Name:api Properties:{Name: URL:url}}]}]}
```

If you want to read from a yaml file, in the main func just replace:

```
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &y)
```

with

```
yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("yaml_sample.yaml")
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("yamlFile.Get err   #%v ", err)
}
err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &y)
```

Comment: Thanks 1+ , Can you please provide example how would you parse the file in the answer to this struct ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I've tried your example and it works partially the `install`  `properties`  `provides` objects are empty , any idea ?

Comment: Sorry this is Ok the problem is with vs code debugger, it appear that it doesnt show object in deep struct...see my update, you cannot open the array object to see whats in there

Comment: my last question :) if you need to build this golang program how would you structre the project , lets say the main is under `rootProj-> cmd>main.go`  where do you put all the `struct' (which folder in the proj and if you create new file for each struct ...)and how you load them to the main method. thank a lot!

Comment: If the app is all that from this question description you might keep it all in one file. The final design of your app should depend on your full requirements and complexity. This feels like another question and it is too generic. Could you please separate it to another StackOverflow question and provide more specifics.